# imagePickerController image orientation seems to be incorrect

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I've got an `imagePickerController` `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` implementation where I'm taking an image from the Camera and storing it as a local file:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    print(info)

    if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] {
        if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image as! UIImage) {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("CurrentProfilePicture.png")
            data.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)
        }
    }
    self.imageController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm then displaying the image to the user with the following code in `ViewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("CurrentProfilePicture.png")
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(filename) {
            let Profileimage1 = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filename)
            let ciImage = CIImage(image: Profileimage1!)
            let orientation1: UIImageOrientation = (Profileimage1?.imageOrientation)!
            profileImage.image = UIImage(CIImage: ciImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation:orientation1)
        }

}
```

If I just load the `UIImage` straight into the `UIImageView` I get the incorrect orientation. I tried the above and I still get the incorrect orientation. The Photo was taken with the camera in portrait with the phone the correct way up and it comes out rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise. If I check the data returned from the info dictionary in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method it states orientation 3 although I'm not sure what this relates to. When the image is loaded in `ViewDidAppear` the orientation that is returned is "Up" but this is obviously incorrect. If I turn the phone landscape the orientation is again wrong.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: i was in problem where image is in wrong orientations , i have method to set orientation ok , but it is in obj c  do you need it ?

Comment: @MikeAlter It might be helpful to show why the image was the incorrect orientation, but I'd need to port the method to swift.

Comment: because of PNG Representation of image , it creates issues

Comment: when i was create png representation  of image it shows wrong orientation, after selection from image picker i change scale and orientation